# c source code to remove subset transactions from text file

Tags: c++, c, file, file-handling

I have a file containing data as follows

```
10 20 30 40 70
20 30 70
30 40 10 20
29 70
80 90 20 30 40
40 45 65 10 20 80
45 65 20
```

I want to remove all subset transaction from this file.

output file should be like follows

```
10 20 30 40 70
29 70
80 90 20 30 40
40 45 65 10 20 80
```

Where records like

```
20 30 70
30 40 10 20
45 65 20
```

are removed because of they are subset of other records.

Comment: What code did you try to solve this?

Comment: What are the rules which determine one sequence of numbers as a subset of some other sequence of numbers? The example seems ambiguous to me.

Comment: I want to remove all subsets from the transactional database

Answer (score 1):

the algorithm could be like this:

```
sets = list()
f = open("data.txt")

for line in f:
    currentSet = set()
    for item in line.split():
        currentSet.add(int(item))
    printIt = True
    for s in sets:
        if currentSet.issubset(s):
            printIt = False
            break
    if printIt:
        print line,
        sets.append(currentSet)
```

Incidentally, this is also a Python program :) Also I believe that an algorithm with better effeciency could be made.

Your next step: rewrite this to C/C++. Good luck :)

Comment: Giving an algorithm in the wrong language is a nice answer to a give-me-the-code question. Here, have a cookie. `:)`